# Showing password in url when submitting form to backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have created a login form to send data to backend and verify ,if correct then send 200 status code.
I have created backend used bcryptjs to hash password in database. The problem is that when form is submitted getting the email and password in url after submitting and that is a real security issue.

my code

frontend :

```
const Form = ({ sendprop }) => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });
function onFormChange(e) {
    console.log("target : "+e.target.value);
    setFormValue({ ...formValue, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(formValue);
  }

  // const chooseFormMethod=(prop)=>{
  //   if(prop==="signup"){
  //       handleSubmit  
  //   }
  // }
  const handleSubmit=async(e,prop)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(prop==="signup"){
      console.log("in handleSubmit")
      if(formValue.password===formValue.confirmPassword){
          console.log("in if")
          const res=await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/signup',{
              ...formValue
          })
          console.log(res);
      }
    }
    else{
      const {email,password}=formValue
      const body={
        email:email,
        password:password
      }
      const res= await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login',body);
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
;
  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{handleSubmit(e,sendprop)}}>
        <div id="input-div">
          {sendprop === "signup" ? <NameInput passState={{formValue,setFormValue}}/> : " "}
          <input
            type={"email"}
            placeholder="E m a i l  A d d r e s s"
            id="email-input"
            className="form-input"
            name="email"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.email}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          <input
            type={"password"}
            placeholder="P a s s w o r d"
            id="password-input"
            className="form-input"
            name="password"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.password}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          {sendprop === "signup" ? <ConfirmPassword passState={{formValue,setFormValue}}/> : " "}
        </div>
        <div id="submit-btn-div">
          <button type={"submit"} id="submit-btn">
            S U B M I T
          </button>
        </div>
        {sendprop === "signup" ? <LoginAccount /> : " "}
        {sendprop !== "signup" ? <CreateAccount /> : " "}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

**backend**

login api:

```
router.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
    const {name,email,password}=req.body;
    const  data = await UserSchemaModel.findOne({email});
    console.log(data);
    try{
        if(data===null){
            res.status(403).send({message:"email doesnt exist"});
        }
        else{
            isMatch=await bcryptjs.compare(password,data.password);
            if(!isMatch){
               res.status(401).send({message:"password doesnt match"});
            }
            else{
                res.status(200).send({
                    msg: 'success',
                    statusCode: res.statusCode
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send({error});
    }
})
```

Comment: Html `<form>` default behaviour is get so you can use `method ='post'`
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/method#:~:text=The%20HTMLFormElement.,default%20method%20is%20'get'.)

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<form>` default method is `get`.
Get method appends the parameters to URL.

There are two ways to do this.

```html
const handleSubmit=async(e,prop)=>{
return false
}

<form onSubmit={(e)=>{handleSubmit(e,sendprop)}}> 
</form>
```

or use `<form method='post'>`